# Octave - Split number into matrix

Tags: matrix, octave

Using Octave I want to take a number for example

```
x = 14
```

And split it into a matrix like the following.

```
m = [1, 4]
```

So far I've tried converting the number into a string, and then using the str2mat function without result.

Another example would be

```
x = 23445
```

Converted to

```
m = [2, 3, 4, 4, 5]
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: you mention trying to use the `str2mat` function. That function was deprecated with Octave 3.2.0 which is already a very old version of Octave. I suggest you upgrade it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x = 14;
sprintf('%d',x) - '0'
>> 1 4
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this via string manipulation, provided there's no decimal parts, this is the way to go:

```
octave> x = 23445    
x = 23445
octave> s = int2str (x)
s = 23445
octave> m = arrayfun (@(x) str2double (s(x)), 1:numel(s))
m =

   2   3   4   4   5
```

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but the idea is: try to divide the number `x = 23445` by 10 and take the decimal part.

For example, iterate:

```
x = 23445;
t = 23445/10;     # t is 2344,5
r = floor(t);     # r is 2344
d = x - r * 10    # d is 5 = 23445 - 2344 * 10
```

`d` will have value 5 (you have the last digit of `x`, add it to the array). `r` will have value 2344. So now:

```
x = r;            # so x = 2344;
t = 2344/10;      # t is 234,4
r = floor(t);     # r is 234
d = x - r * 10    # d is 4 = 2344 - 234 * 10
```

`d` will have value 4. `r` will have value 234. 
And iterate till `r = 0`.

Comment: Thanks, interesting approach, I'll give this a try. Seems computationally expensive.

Comment: Another aproach is to convert the number to string `num2str` and then iterate the characters of the string. Don't know if it's possible to do that with octave...